# "@" symbol being interpreted as new line in unix terminal

Tags: linux, unix, ssh

I am trying to copy SSH keys from one server to another using scp commands like below.

```
scp $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@servername:~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

However, as soon as I enter this command, the result comes as below.

```
scp $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@<BR>
servername:~/.ssh/authorized_keys<BR>
ksh: servername:~/.ssh/authorized_keys:  not found
```

What I believe is that the terminal is interpreting the `@` symbol as new line. This is because, whenever I type `@` on the terminal, it simply goes into new line. How can I resolve this?

Platform: AIX 64 bit.

Comment: Try this: `scp $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@servername:.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: Issue is with the @ symbol. tilde character is not a problem. Also i found the solution. Same i have posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue got resolved. The problem was with my .profile. Not really sure what was the problem as it had lots of commands which i was not able to understand.

I replaced it with the default .profile which was present in some other user.

Further, i found solution to above problem by using escape character. Instead of using command mentioned in above issue, i used as below.

scp $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user\@servername:~/.ssh/authorized_keys